# VBA XMLHTTP JSON-response contains escaped forward slashes as well as unicode chars like \u00f6 for Umlaute

Tags: json, vba, xmlhttprequest

I am sending a POST request with a GraphQL-query via VBA with `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` which looks like the following:

```
req.Open "POST", reqURL, False

req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8"

reqBody = "<graphql>"

req.Send reqBody
```

`req.responseText` contains the valid JSON-response, but forward slashes are escaped plus Umlaute are encoded like `\u00f6` for example.

Is there any possibility to receive the JSON-String as I would request it via JavaScript?

Kind regards
Philipp

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

https://gist.github.com/yadimon/ce1d04b88de17064bfae for unescaping utf-8, plus just replacing backslashes with `replace(string, "\", "")`